# minimum width(of browser) to display the collpase button of nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can we set width of browser to display the collapse button of a navigation bar in bootstrap??
I think media queries may help me with this..but i don't know to set min width of browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query for this. For example, this would make the collapse button toggle at 1280 pixels..

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/98488

Comment: Menu didn't stay open after toggle button is clicked.I think we should include

.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap-3,you can use col

```
<div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
```

for details http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ the @grid-float-breakpoint is the last field in this screen shot, there you can enter the breakpoint (@screen-sm-min - 768px, @screen-mid-min - 992px) of where you want the menu to turn into the collapsed version.

[image: Customizer]